# Is normal mapping cpu overhead or gpu overhead?

Tags: unity, normal-mapping

In Unity3D Engine,

I usually apply normal mapping using fragment shader.

In this case,

this normal mapping is cpu overhead or gpu overhead?

Comment: If you use fragment shader, isn't it necessarily the GPU? (I'm new to gamedev)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Unity, but more often than not (almost always), shaders are run on gpu hardware.

Comment: So you mean it's GPU overhead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal mapping is calculated using a vertex and pixel shader, so it's GPU overhead.